# How can I configure Vim to compile C code using Borland's compiler on Windows?

Tags: c, vim, borland-c++

I am new to the text editor Vim. I want to use it for programming 
C. I am using Windows and the `bcc32` compiler from Borland.
I cannot seem to get my C code to compile.
I think something is wrong with my setup. Can someone give step by step information
on how to setup Vim for compiling using BCC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not used the bcc32 compiler, but I'm assuming it uses a different make tool than `make`.  You'll need to put:

`set makeprg=<make command>`

Somewhere in your `.vimrc` file.

Answer (score 1):

A Google search of vim and bcc led me to this page.

http://ftp.nluug.nl/vim/runtime/compiler/bcc.vim

You'll have to place this bcc.vim in the ~/vimfiles/compiler directory

Comment: Almost. It must be placed in the ~/vimfiles/compiler/ directory.

Comment: I've changed the line:
let current_compiler = "bcc"
to
let current_compiler = "bcc32"