# Why won't Vim compile my C code?

Tags: vim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I configure Vim to compile C code using Borland’s compiler on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153768/how-can-i-configure-vim-to-compile-c-code-using-borlands-compiler-on-windows)

I have been trying to compile a simply c code using Gvim 7.2.
I have the Borland `bcc32` compiler installed, but I keep getting the message
"make is not recognized as an internal or external command".

What am I doing wrong? What should I include in my `_virmrc` file to
correct the problem or what configuration do I need to set to compile my code?

Comment: If you use more exclamation points, that means people will answer your question more quickly.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153768/how-can-i-configure-vim-to-compile-c-code-using-borlands-compiler-on-windows by the same user

Comment: Well, the answer is simple: because Vim wasn't compiled with the +cc and +c++ options, obviously :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added the directory with Borland's `make.exe` to your `%PATH%`?

Right click on My Computer → Properties → Advanced → Environment Variables

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Introduction to Programming in C/C++ with Vim](http://www.justlinux.com/nhf/Programming/Introduction_to_C_Programming.html).

In this situation VIM is looking for your `make.exe`. Either put this on the path, or set the variable **makeprg** e.g.

```
:set makeprg={path to your make exe}
```

Answer (score 2):

That error suggests that Vim cannot find `make`.

Troubleshooting steps:

- Is `make` installed?
- Is the directory containing the `make` executable in your path?
- Can you run `make` from the command line?
- Can you run `make` from inside of vim?

Information that would help:

- Which version of Windows are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Is the path to make in your system path?  I would check there first.